# Documention no longer builds in Workbench

Tags: workbench

I recently installed the l[atest Wolfram Workbench](https://www.wolfram.com/workbench/) plugin in my eclipse IDE (Neon.1a Release 4.6.1). Then I attempted to follow this old tutorial on generating docs with the documentation tool pallete: http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=93&v=899

[image]

When pressing build I reiceved this message:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> /Users/admin/Documents/eclipse_workspace/test/docbuild.xml:132: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/admin/Documents/eclipse_workspace/test/docbuild.xml:90: taskdef
>   A class needed by class com.wolfram.jlink.util.MathematicaTask cannot
>   be found: org/apache/tools/ant/Task  using the classloader AntClassLoader[/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/JLink.jar]

Comment: Eclipse comes in multiple versions.  Install the plugin into the Java development version, not any other.  Let us know if it works now.  Also make sure that you have a JDK (not JRE) installed.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs I was using c++ not java, now it works.

Comment: I reported this more than a month ago, and suggested correcting this article: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/27221  The article says: "Note that the Wolfram Workbench plugin is compatible with the various standard Eclipse IDEs."  After your experience I am convinced that this is not correct.

Comment: Btw, do you know of any great DocumentationTools tutorials :)

Comment: The best I know is the official docs: http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp and the videos you already know about.

Comment: Ooof, that's old, but thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you see this error:

> A class needed by class `com.wolfram.jlink.util.MathematicaTask` cannot be found: `org/apache/tools/ant/Task`

then try installing the Workbench plugin into "Eclipse for Java Developers".

It seems other versions, e.g. "Eclipse for C++ Developers", lack some components that the Workbench plugin needs.

Also make sure to have the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) (not JRE) installed.

---

The Workbench support article at http://support.wolfram.com/kb/27221 says,

> Note that the Wolfram Workbench plugin is compatible with the various standard Eclipse IDEs.

I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: I do use Eclipse for C/C++ developers, so I doubt it is strictly necessary to download the one for Java. But it needed some extra configuration, and I have to check whether that involved adding the JDT component. I agree the support article should be corrected if it does not work "out of the box".